# Javascript random image on click button

Tags: javascript, html

I've been following some tutorials on how to randomize an image by setting up an array in Javascript.  It's not working - the image itself is not appearing, not even any error.

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function randomImg1(){
        var myImages1 = new Array ();
        myImages1[1] = "img/who/1.jpg";
        myImages1[2] = "img/who/2.jpg";
        myImages1[3] = "img/who/3.jpg";
        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages1.length);
        if(rnd == 0{
            rnd = 1;
        }
        document.write(<img class="who" src="'+myImages1[rnd]);
    }
</script>
```

and my button looks like this

```
<input class="randombutton" style="float: left;" type="button" value="Randomize" onclick="randomImg1()"/>
```

Comment: You need to add quotes around what you're writing: `document.write('<img class="who" src="'+myImages1[rnd])+'">);` and you never finished your `img` tag.

Comment: Your array should be 0,1,2 not 1,2,3. You're missing the closing paren on `if (rnd == 0` - that line goes away anyway. You can't use `document.write` after the page is loaded - it will kill the whole page - you need to put the value into a container. You're missing the quotes and closing angle-bracket on the `img` tag that you're writing.

Comment: Doesn't your "random generator" mostly be 1? Just wondering if you should write a more random number generating logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man, this is embarrassing.  Crazy how much you can learn in 3 years.  I think the most optimal way of doing this would be the following (assuming there is no folder structure pattern).  Haven't tested but should work.

```
var images = ["img/who/1.jpg","img/who/2.jpg","img/who/3.jpg"];

function getRandomImage(){
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    return images[rnd];
}

function changeImage(){
    var img = document.querySelector("#myImg");
    img.src = getRandomImage();
}

function init(){
    var el = document.querySelector(".myClass");
    el.onclick = changeImage;
}

window.onload = init;
```

What was I thinking assigning an array to `[1]` and then doing an `if` check?  I'll never know.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add quotes in this line and close the if statement:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function randomImg1() {
    var myImages1 = new Array();
    myImages1[1] = "img/who/1.jpg";
    myImages1[2] = "img/who/2.jpg";
    myImages1[3] = "img/who/3.jpg";
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages1.length);
    if (rnd == 0) {
            rnd = 1;
    }
    document.write('<img class="who" src="' + myImages1[rnd] + '">');
}
</script>
```

Comment: You will also have to close the img tag

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `)` in your if statement and on your document.write you missed `'` and closing the `<img>` tag. Check here:

```
if (rnd == 0) {
        rnd = 1;
    }

document.write('<img class="who" src="' + myImages1[rnd] + '"/>');
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel a bit silly that I failed because of a semantics error but I guess it's all part of learning a code...
I do have one other question;  I thought document.write would append to my document, but it seems to replace everything.  How would I go about solving this/using a different method?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to keep track of all your closing brackets and parenthesis.

This code will work for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function randomImg1() {
      var myImages1 = new Array ();
      myImages1[1] = "img/who/1.jpg";
      myImages1[2] = "img/who/2.jpg";
      myImages1[3] = "img/who/3.jpg";
      var rnd = Math.floor( Math.random() * myImages1.length );
      if( rnd == 0 ) {
        rnd =1;
      }
      html_code = '<img class="who" src="' + myImages1[rnd] + '" />";
      document.write(html_code);
    }
</script>
```

Also if I were you, I would point to a more specific point in your DOM document.. You could use a very simple jQuery script like this if you want: `$("#testing").html(html_code);` instead of your `document.write()`

Comment: Awesome, now I can target specific parts of the document, too.

Answer (score 1):

To APPEND something in your page to an element in the HTML, use

```
.append
```

rather than the "write" function, as .append will actually APPEND content to a specified element, rather than all over your whole DOCUMENT.

So, in your HTML, you should create a DIV with ID "our_div"

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- Text will be appended to this DIV via JS -->
<div id="the_div">Hello, </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Use something like this:

```
function add_text() {
  $("#the_div").append("World"); // appends text "World" to the end of that div.
}
```

Now, inside your HTML, you should have a button that calls the function "add_text()".

```
<button id="the_button" onClick="add_text();">Click Here to Add Text</button>
```

Now then!

When a user clicks the button, it will append the text "World" to the DIV with ID "the_div..." THUS, we have...

```
Hello, World
```

Here's the entire code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function add_text() {
  $("#the_div").append("World");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="the_div">
Hello, 
</div>
<button id="the_button" onClick="add_text();">Click!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Try using

```
.html
```

to REPLACE something... For example, I use a Dice Roll Function in a game I have developed. When a player rolls the dice...

```
$("#results").append(Math.floor(Math.rand()*6));
```

gives us something like this...

(every roll)

```
results: 142563342515246422
```

and if I use .html...

```
$("#results").html(Math.floor(Math.rand()*6));
```

we are left with something more like this

(first roll)

```
results: 5
```

(second roll)

```
results: 2
```

(third roll)

```
results: 6
```

And so on!

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you are writing to your document is incomplete.

You need something like:

```
document.write("<img class='who' src='" + myImages1[rnd] + "'>");
```

I would also caution that document.write is not normally a preferred method of adding elements to the page, but it seems that this is more a learning example than a real world example.

Answer (score -1):

This is the best way I can think of, the reason I prefer this, is because instead of changing the whole page, it just changes the *src* in the *img* tag.

Here's the code:

**Script**

```
function imgchange() {

var myImages1 = new Array();
    myImages1[1] = "img/who/1.jpg";
    myImages1[2] = "img/who/2.jpg";
    myImages1[3] = "img/who/3.jpg";
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages1.length);
    if (rnd == 0) {
            rnd = 1;
    }

  document.getElementById("gen-img").src = myImages1[rnd];

}
```

**Html**

```
<p><img id="gen-img" src="img/who/1.jpg"></p>
<p><input type="button" value="Random" onclick="imgchange();" /></p>
```

What I do however, is I have a blank png file with nothing in it, and I set that as the default *src* for my image. But you can do as you please.