# Random images on click (three times)

Tags: javascript, image, random, onclick

I made a simple page with three images (a head, torso and legs). By pressing the three buttons (head, torso, legs), one of them changes randomly: http://matti.tv/VRT/

My problem: the heads show up at random without flaws, but the torso and legs give errors ("undefined"). I tried to fix it, but I'm just not an expert and my code is very messy.

I followed the tips in an [earlier topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933158/javascript-random-image-on-click-button) about random images on clicking a button, but it seems I'm doing something wrong by using two extra random image generators and I just can't figure it out.

I know I should be putting my three myImages in one function, but how do I call them later on in the img and button?

```
<script>
    function imgchange1() {    
        var myImages1 = new Array();
        myImages1[1] = "1.jpg";
        myImages1[2] = "2.jpg";        
        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages1.length);
        if (rnd == 0) {
            rnd = 1;
        }    
        document.getElementById("gen-img1").src = myImages1[rnd];    
    }

    function imgchange2() {    
        var myImages2 = new Array();
        myImages2[19] = "19.jpg";
        myImages2[20] = "20.jpg";
        myImages2[21] = "21.jpg";

        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages2.length);
        if (rnd == 0) {
            rnd = 1;
        }    
        document.getElementById("gen-img2").src = myImages2[rnd];    
    }

    function imgchange3() {    
        var myImages3 = new Array();
        myImages3[46] = "46.jpg";
        myImages3[47] = "47.jpg";
        myImages3[48] = "48.jpg";

        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages3.length);
        if (rnd == 0) {
            rnd = 1;
        }    
        document.getElementById("gen-img3").src = myImages3[rnd];    
    }

</script>
<center>
    <p><img id="gen-img1" src="7.jpg"></p>    
    <p><img id="gen-img2" src="20.jpg"></p>        
    <p><img id="gen-img3" src="46.jpg"></p>    
</center>    
<center>
    <p>            
        <input type="button" value="Hoofd" onclick="imgchange1();" />
        <input type="button" value="Torso" onclick="imgchange2();" />
        <input type="button" value="Benen" onclick="imgchange3();" />
    </p>        
</center>
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and take particular note of the link to debugging small programs at the bottom.

Comment: Have you noticed that on the other issue you are referring to , it was said that you should use  "'myImages1[rnd]'"; inside double then single quotes

Comment: if u can post any plunker for ur code would be better, and u can use any url of images online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are pushing items to your `myImages2` & `mymyImages3` with index starting from `19` & `46` respectively but it has to be started from `1`.

```
myImages2[1]="19.jpg";
myImages2[2]="20.jpg";
.
.
```

&

```
myImages3[1]="46.jpg";
myImages3[2]="19.jpg";
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

In every function the random values were ranging from 0 to array length, but while storing the src, it was like arr[17], arr[18]

Please check the snippet below:

```js
function imgchange1() {

  var myImages1 = new Array();
  myImages1[1] = "http://www.logologo.com/logos/flower-logo.jpg";
  myImages1[2] = "https://www.logobee.com/uploads/free-logo1.jpg";
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages1.length);
  if (rnd == 0) {
    rnd = 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("gen-img1").src = myImages1[rnd];
}

function imgchange2() {

  var myImages2 = new Array();
  myImages2[1] = "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-and-colorful-logo_23-2147504722.jpg";
  myImages2[2] = "http://www.logospike.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Free_Logo_03.jpg";
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages2.length);
  if (rnd == 0) {
    rnd = 1;
  }
  console.log(myImages2[rnd]);
  document.getElementById("gen-img2").src = myImages2[rnd];

}

function imgchange3() {

  var myImages3 = new Array();
  myImages3[1] = "http://www.logologo.com/logos/globe-swooshes-logo.jpg";
  myImages3[2] = "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/infinite-logo_23-2147515990.jpg";
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages3.length);
  if (rnd == 0) {
    rnd = 1;
  }

  document.getElementById("gen-img3").src = myImages3[rnd];

}
```

```html
<center>
  <p>
    <img id="gen-img1" src="http://www.logologo.com/logos/flower-logo.jpg">
  </p>

  <p>
    <img id="gen-img2" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-and-colorful-logo_23-2147504722.jpg">
  </p>

  <p>
    <img id="gen-img3" src="http://www.logologo.com/logos/globe-swooshes-logo.jpg">
  </p>

</center>

<center>
  <p>

    <input type="button" value="Hoofd" onclick="imgchange1();" />
    <input type="button" value="Torso" onclick="imgchange2();" />
    <input type="button" value="Benen" onclick="imgchange3();" />
  </p>

</center>
```

Comment: hey @Meurisse I have created a dummy code with two image per slot. Please let me know if you have any confusion. But try changing the data structure here. The images should be stored once in some dataStructure. In the click callbacks, only generate the random number, and fetch the image corresponding to that index. Every time creating a separate array with same image src is performance hitting step. Please avoid that.