# Randomize background image using button onClick event

Tags: html, css, image, random, background

I want to randomize the background image when the user clicks a button.

[Here's what I have.](http://rsch.neocities.org/photos.html)

Every time the button at the bottom right is cliked, I want to randomize the background image from a set array of externally hosted images.

How can I achieve that? (Without PHP, if possible.)

Comment: You should not post you website here. Just show some code and ask for what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function randomImg1() {
      var myImages1 = new Array ();
      myImages1[1] = "img/who/1.jpg";
      myImages1[2] = "img/who/2.jpg";
      myImages1[3] = "img/who/3.jpg";
      var rnd = Math.floor( Math.random() * myImages1.length );
      if( rnd == 0 ) {
        rnd =1;
      }
      html_code = '<img class="who" src="' + myImages1[rnd] + '" />";
      document.write(html_code);
    }
</script>
```

You can also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933158/javascript-random-image-on-click-button)

`// EDIT -- By Pipskweak`

instead of

```
html_code = '<img class="who" src="' + myImages1[rnd] + '" />";
document.write(html_code);
```

we could do this;

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute('style','background-image: url(' + myImages1[rnd] + ')');
```

after all, background image was mentioned.

Comment: I simply used `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + myImages1[rnd] + ")";`. Worked fine otherwise, thanks!